# Why aren't metaclass's attributes searched in instance attribute lookups?

Tags: python, attributes, metaclass, python-internals, getattribute

According to Python 2.7.12 documentation, 3.4.2.3. Invoking Descriptors¶:

> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete
>   the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, `a.x` has a
>   lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then
>   `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of
>   `type(a)` **excluding metaclasses**.

But why metaclasses are excluded?

If you continuously call `type(self)`, no matter what `self` is, an instance object or a type object, you'll eventually get `<type 'type'>`. So I can't understand why metaclasses enjoy this "privilege".

---

By the way, I'm a little confused by this quotation: For instance objects, `object.__getattribute__` are used, so I think the lookup chain should look like this:

- `a.__dict__['x']`
- `type(a).__dict__['x']`
- `b.__dict__[x]` for `b` in `type(a).__mro__`
- `type(b).__dict__[x]` for `b` in `type(a).__mro__`
- `c.__dict__[x]` for `c` in `type(b).__mro__`
- ......

Am I right?

Comment: I see you are experimenting with metaclasses and attribut access  - any reason you are not uisng Python 3?  Almost any project can use Python 3 today, and tehre are a lot of features/changes that did not make it into Python2

Comment: @jsbueno Hmm...For compatibility, I guess. My college(my classmate, actually. We are working on a project together.) recommended me to learn Python2 first, because many modules haven't support Python3 yet, and they may not support it in the near future. My experiments are for understanding how Python works in the background better, and they will be helpful if I decide to switch to Python3 someday, right?

Comment: I think the "many modules does not have Python 3 support yet" is not true as from 2015 on. Most important thngs nowadys do work in Python3, and above all, for the deep understanding you are seeking, I'd say Python3 is much more relevant. Python 's2  end of line is scheduled for 2020. If you start a project today, that is 3 years before having to migrate it - I would not say it is worth it.

Comment: @jsbueno Well, maybe we should really use Python 3, for it is the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the attribute lookup searches all **bases** of `type(a)`(`type(a).__mro__`), rather than all **types** of `type(a)`(`type(type(a))`).

Also, `type(self)` is not called continuously, so the lookup chain looks like this:

- `a.__dict__['x']`
- `type(a).__dict__['x']`
- `b.__dict__[x] for b in type(a).__mro__`
- `raise AttributeError`

As @jsbueno wisely pointed out in the comment, the second step is actually included in the third one. This is because for any class, let's say class `C`, `C` itself is exactly the first item in `C.__mro__`.

Comment: Actually, the second step is included in the third - to understand what happens, `type(a).__dict__['x']` verification is included in `b.__dict__[x] for b in type(a).__mro__`

Comment: @jsbueno Yes you are right. A class `C` itself is exactly the first item in `C.__mro__`. Answer edited.